# How to create Rest API with Jax-rs Backend in Liferay Dev Studio?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, liferay, liferay-service-builder

I'm trying to implement a **REST API** with **JAX-RS** using to deploy it in **Liferay 7.2** and consume it with a **React JS** application as the font-end .

Until now I don't know how to create a good **project structure** to start my back-end project!

My Rest API is connected to a two tables **database**, how can I add them to the project? and where I have to work in the project to create my **controllers and application's business logic**?

I tried to create a project and it looks like this for now.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: you can get the default API for your table. API related  method are in -API suffix folder. You need to create one portlet to write your Controller level business logic.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you created a Liferay **service-builder** project. No need to do that as you are not building any Liferay services. Start with a Liferay **rest** project. This will automatically create the necessary files for a JAX-RS application.